# GIMP: Getting something from "Gfig" to the Image being edited?

Tags: gimp

For lines/boxes, I found an answer by
k0pernikus on this site someone advised using Select Filters > Render > Gfig... From there you can draw boxes and other shapes boxes in various styles.

I opened it up - great! BUT How do you get the box, line or shape actually onto the Img you're editing in GIMP???

Answer (score 2):

Gfig creates a new transparent layer on the image, and objects created there are automatically rendered as pixels on this new layer. On closing gfig, your objects should be just there, in a new layer - no further actions are needed.

Comment: You are correct - it turned out I somehow had a blank layer beneath what I was looking at... sorry to waste time. Appreciate your answer.